# Obtaining the integral:$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}f^n(t)dt$

Tags: integration

I have the following integral in my notes:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}f^n(t)dt=\Big[ e^{st}f^{n-1}(t)-(-s)e^{-st}f^{n-2}(t)+(-s)^2e^{-st}f^{n-3}(t)+\ldots\ldots+(-1)^{n-1}(-s)^{n-1}e^{-st}f(t)\Big]_{0}^{\infty}+(-1)^n(-s)^{n}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}f(t)dt$$   ,where $f^n(t)$ represents $n^{th}$ derivative of $f(t)$

I can't understand how is this integration obtained .Kindly help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply integration by parts several times: The first time you get 
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f^n(t)dt = e^{-st}f^{n-1}(t)|_0^\infty -\int_0^\infty(-s)e^{-st}f^{n-1}(t)dt.
$$ 
Continue this until you get rid of all derivatives of $f$.